# Gradient text color in a custom view

Tags: android, textview, gradient, android-custom-view

I have this GradientTextView class that extends AppCompatTextView

```
public class GradientTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

public GradientTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    //Setting the gradient if layout is changed
    if (changed) {
        getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(),
                ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorStart),//Red Color
                ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorEnd),// Blue Color
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    }
}
```

}

and here is the xml of gradient textview

```
<package.GradientTextView
        android:id="@+id/textLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login."
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
```

Right now I have a textview with a red and blue gradient.
I would like to change the gradient color dinamically.

What's the best way to change the color programatically?

After answer of @Nicola Gallazzi I am updating my question Now new file of GradientTextView is

```
public class GradientTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {


int colorStart = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorStart);
int colorEnd = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorEnd);

public GradientTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    //Setting the gradient if layout is changed
    if (changed) {
        getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), colorStart, colorEnd,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    }
}

public void setGradientColors(int colorStart, int colorEnd) {
    this.colorStart = colorStart;
    this.colorEnd = colorEnd;
    // this forces view redrawing
    invalidate();
}
```

}

but here is a new problem that is when I am using this in activity like @Nicola Gallazzi is shows error.

**CODE**

```
        textView.setGradientColors(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.ncolorEnd, R.color.ncolorStart));
```

**ERROR**

[image: Here you can find the error which]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define your colorStart and colorEnd as instance variables of your `GradientTextView` class.
Then, define a **public** method within the class to set the colorStart and the colorEnd programmatically:

```java
public class GradientTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    private int colorStart = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary);
    private int colorEnd = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorAccent);


    public GradientTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        //Setting the gradient if layout is changed
        if (changed) {
            getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), colorStart, colorEnd,
                    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        }
    }

    public void setGradientColors(int colorStart, int colorEnd) {
        this.colorStart = colorStart;
        this.colorEnd = colorEnd;
        // this forces view redrawing
        invalidate();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: bro I have one doubt in Paint Instance . What is R.color.startColor?

Comment: You mean R.color.colorStart? I copy and pasted it from the question

Comment: and one more doubt . How to use it is programmatically?

Comment: Ok according to my question R.color.colorStart is a reference of red color and R.color.colorEnd is reference of Blue color which is defined in color.xml file

Comment: Bro Not working. Can you please tell Me How to use it?

Comment: bro did you check your code because copy of your code it shows error in java file.

Comment: setGradientColors in shaderActivity

Comment: You have to put your own colors there, update the question with current code

Comment: Now I have been updated my answer. You can check it out.

Comment: @BlackBlind response updated. You should define R.color.newStartColor and R.color.newEndColor in your colors.xml file or choose two existing colors of yours

Comment: Bro now it is not show a gradient in output. It is showing a default color of text.

Comment: @BlackBlind code updated, I tested it and now it works. You should use getPaint() inside onLayout which is the paint of your view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190291/discussion-between-blackblind-and-nicola-gallazzi).

Comment: bro can you share your code or can you come in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190342/discussion-between-blackblind-and-nicola-gallazzi).

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply create the gradient drawable from the java code like below-

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.setStroke(width, Color.RED);
drawable.setCornerRadius(8);
drawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorRed));
```

And set the drawable to imageview like below

```
    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: bro I am coloring a gradient color in text not set a background as a gradient.?

Comment: Use setColors method to set different colors in the gradient.
Check this link for reference of GradientDrawable
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable

Comment: I do not want drawable